# How to navigate between pages in windows phone 8.1RT

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I am a new programmer for windows phone and I finally tried creating multi-paged apps.
I am trying to move between the main page to a blank page.
I use the following code:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

the app crashes and I get the following error:
The program has exited with code -1073741189
I looked online but using a dispatcher doesn't help either. I'm clueless.
How Can I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to say with so little code. Foe example it may depend when you try to navigate - this process is asynchronous and if previous navigation has not ended, you may get an exception. Please provide more details.

Comment: I have not navigated to any pages. It is inside a button press

Comment: Have you modified somehow the constructor of BlankPage1 or its xaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that the exception was raised at a different point in the compilation of the new page and thus the whole program crashed. If you have this error just debug line by line until you find an exception. My code was long so it took me a day or two but usually debugging will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourType))?

We really do need to see more code though..

Comment: Doesn't work.
I edited the code in to the original question